How to use different pointers and keyboard for different monitors
I have a system running on top of Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop which I use along with an external monitor. I am trying to work on both simultaneously and I want to be using separate input methods for separate monitors.
I have a logitech keyboard and mouse. I want all my input to the logitech mouse and keyboard to go to the window open on my external monitor and all input done on my laptop's keyboard and touchpad to go to the laptop's monitor. I also want separate mouse pointers for each display
I tried using Multi-Pointer X from here.
I reattached my logitech keyboard and mouse to another master and now the input goes to whichever window the respective mouse pointer have selected(if I have selected Editor in Display 1 using touchpad and terminal in display two using logitech mouse the input of respective keyboards also feeds input in the respective windows) .
Now the problem is that the secondary mouse pointer is flickering and the mouse wheel is not working as intended in the extended display and the active window in the monitor with the secondary pointer is always changing as to where the cursor's position(as if the secondary pointer is always autoclicking). Also the super key and the keyboard shortcuts is not working in remapped keyboard(logitech).
This is my initial and remapped xinput config.
xinput list                   
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4022          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]

xinput list          
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
⎡ Secondary pointer                         id=20   [master pointer  (21)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4022          id=11   [slave  pointer  (20)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=12   [slave  pointer  (20)]
⎜   ↳ Secondary XTEST pointer                   id=22   [slave  pointer  (20)]
⎣ Secondary keyboard                        id=21   [master keyboard (20)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=19   [slave  keyboard (21)]
    ↳ Secondary XTEST keyboard  
What would be a better way to implement my requirement?
